# GitHub README.html

Tags: github

I have a wealth of documentation for a project I would like to make open source (through github).

The problem is that github README does not support .html files.

I tried `html2text` with absolutely horrid results.

Is there a fast easy way to convert naturalDocs(or any html documentation) type output to a git readme?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) to publish your documentation and write a short information with a link to that in your README file using RDoc or Markdown format.

Answer (score 11):

You could convert it "back" to Markdown via one of the following methods:

1. http://fvsch.com/code/remarkdown/
2. https://tibastral.github.io/markdownify/
3. http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try

Good luck